# Remembering the device and reconnecting to it

Tags: javascript, html, web-bluetooth

I'm currently doing a project with the web bluetooth in js and I wonder if there is a way to save the device object and automatically connecting to it instead of choosing the device in the pop up every time.

I've tried saving the device in the local storage and tried to get it in the cookies but they both failed.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: yeah I forgot to mention tried to save it in the local storage and get it in the cookies and it didn't work

Comment: I'm having the same problem, there doesn't seem to be a way to connect to a BLE device without going through navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice() to get the device object first. That means triggering the popup.

I would hope there was some other API to get a list of paired devices which I can then connect to, but I haven't found any such API.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, but it implies enabling some Chrome feature flags on a [Chrome 85+](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5180688812736512)

You can have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h3uAVXJARHrNWaNACUPiQhLt7XI-fFFQoARSs1WgMDM/edit#).

To sum it up, after enabling those two feature-flags in chrome://flags :

- #enable-experimental-web-platform-features
- #web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend

> The Web Bluetooth spec will be updated with the algorithm for getDevices(). The devices returned by getDevices() may contain devices that are not currently in range and connected. The BluetoothDevice::watchAdvertisements() API can be used to detect when Bluetooth devices come into range of the Bluetooth radio. Then calling BluetoothRemoteGATTServer.connect() should resolve successfully if the device is able to be connected to.